# How can I use something like a regex to specify an na_value when importing csv data to pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to use pandas data frames to read, process, and ultimately write to an sql database values from a large set of csv files holding electric power data. Most of the csv columns contain real numbers that I want to import as a float type, and generally this works fine.

But there are a few irregular files -- the data are fetched from power companies over many months -- where one or more of the ostensibly float values are blank. The data exported by the power company simply fills the empty cells with enough spaces to align the columns properly. For example:

```
1033933002    , 107777352     , 10/05/2021   , 28                  , 29761             , 3.49        , 85, 72, 62   
1033933002    , 107777352     , 10/06/2021   , 35                  , 29796             , 4.37        , 84, 73, 64   
1033933002    , 107777352     , 10/07/2021   , 22                  , 29818             , 2.75        , 82, 72, 62   
1033933002    , 107777352     , 10/08/2021   , 29                  , 29847             ,             , 76, 72, 69
1033933002    , 107777352     , 10/09/2021   , 15                  , 29862             , 1.87        , 88, 77, 67   
1033933002    , 107777352     , 10/10/2021   , 26                  , 29888             , 3.24        , 81, 68, 56
```

(notice the blank in column six.)

This causes the pandas.read_csv() function to choke with "Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'".

After a great deal of googling {Tm} around, I've been able to work around this for a specific case by using the 'na_values' parameter to read_csv, thusly:

```
    data = pd.read_csv(fn,
                   header=0,
                   usecols=<list of desired columns>,
                   dtype=<dict of desired types>,
                   na_values=['             '],
                   decimal='.',
                   skip_blank_lines=True,
                   keep_default_na=False,
                   names=<list of desired column names>)
```

BUT this solution hard-codes the number of spaces in the blank cell, and I cannot count on that being constant. Is there a way to pass some sort of simple regex, like '\s*', to the na_values parameter? Or a different solution?

Ta.

Answer (score 0):

So the commas are always exactly separating columns and they cant occur within the fields?

In this case the probably easiest way (or rather, the one where you have the most control on what actually happens) would be to not use pandas for the reading altogether, instead handling the cases you described using row strings and then putting the results into a DataFrame.

```
# get headers as string list by opening one of the files once and getting first row
with open(file_names[0]) as f_in:
    headers = next(f_in).split(",")
storage_dict = {k:[] for k in headers}

for fn in file_names:
    # for each file
    with open(fn) as f_in:
        # skip headers
        headers = next(f_in)
        for line in f_in:
            # split line by comma, remove \n, trim whitespaces
            row_values = [v.strip() for v in line.rstrip().split(",")]
            # replace now empty values with "NA"
            row_values = ["NA" if v == "" else v for v in row_values]
            for h, v in zip(headers, row_values):
                storage_dict[h].append(v)

 data = pd.DataFrame(storage_dict, na_values="NA")
```

You can then set eventual datatypes like this:

```
data[headers[0]] = data[headers[0]].astype(int)
```

Comment: That's a good idea for the problem as I stated it, thanks @ewz93. It opens a new problem, however. In this mishmosh of datafiles there are some from one vendor that actually have embedded newlines in at lest one field (energy cost). This is clearly a mistake on someone's part, but if I use pandas to originally read in the csv file, I can add a short cleaning function to get rid of the linefeed and format the data properly, and then use the pandas.apply function to use the function to fix that column. But simply using python to read through those files, the bad linefeeds are a real problem.

Comment: I see, I guess you could try to fix that in my approach by reading everything as one big string, then splitting that entire string by `","` and putting everything into the columns in chunks of 9 (number of columns). Since the problem you describe comes from `for line in f_in:` which by default splits by `"\n"`.

Comment: Another idea would be to look for occurences of something like `",    "` in the raw file or string, since it seems all non-NA fields contain maximum one space after the comma while the NA fields contain multiple. So you could go into the file and replace `",    "` (comma and four spaces) by something like `", NA "`. Then save and read with pandas (since for pandas number of chars per row can be flexible) and define na_values as `"NA"`.

Comment: Yes, that's an idea. The problem cells are quite rare, however, so this requires me to do pattern matching across virtually all the data. Here's the thing. The fault comes in when pandas tries to do a type conversion: "Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'" That happens in /one/ entry in a series of legit numbers. I feel I should be able to tell pandas to fill odd-ball entries with NaN or None, but I can't figure how to do that?

Comment: It's a little difficult to reproduce your problem because when I try your DataFrame and `read_csv()` it (without any arguments) I do not get an error. I assume you added all these arguments you did to handle whitespaces better? But one of them or their combination probably causes the error. I think there might be a simpler way which will cause the mentioned NA strings to be empty and autocast to `np.NaN`, which is `df = pd.read_csv(fn, skipinitialspace=True)` (without any additional arguments), did you try that option? Trying with your input sample and using that works for me.

Comment: Oh! That is perfect. I didn't fully grasp the import of that option. "Too simple for these times," as wazizname used to say. Thank you, @ewz93.